# Use std::ostrstream::freeze after std::ostrstream::str to prevent memory leak

Tags: c++

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ostrstream/freeze

> Notes After a call to str(), dynamic streams become frozen
>   automatically. A call to freeze(false) is required before exiting the
>   scope in which this ostrstream object was created. otherwise the
>   destructor will leak memory. Also, additional output to a frozen
>   stream may be truncated once it reaches the end of the allocated
>   buffer.

```
std::string Function( const ObjectA & obj )
{
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << obj;

        return os.str( );
}
```

Question> Does this function leak memory due to the missing of call of`std::ostrstream::freeze` after the `str()`?

Comment: This is using a different type. That documentation is for `strstream`, not `stringstream`. I don't know whether that was deliberate.

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake. I should close it as you already pointed out the error. Thank you

Comment: Also do note that `strstreams` are deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

The standard effectively explains (*section D.7.1.1 and D.7.1.2*) that `str()` sets the state of the `strstream` to frozen, and that  `strstreambuf::~strstreambuf()`

> frees the dynamically allocated array object **only if** strmode &
>   allocated != 0 and strmode & **frozen == 0**.

As your `strstream`  (I assume it's a typo to use stringstream here, givent your question) is a local object, it's destroyed when you return, leaking memory.

***Important note:***  `strstream` is deprecated and kept alive only for compatibility issues.  If you'd use `stringstream` you'd have no leaking at as [`stringstream::str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/) uses strings

Comment: Wow, that's pretty bad.

Comment: Yeah !  I guess it's the reason it's in annex D (deprecated)  !

Comment: `strstream` is kept alive pretty much because there's no replacement in the standard library that provides equivalent performance, not really for compatibility.

Comment: @T.C. I'll avoid opinions and strictly refer to introduction of appendix D:  "*These are deprecated features, where deprecated is defined as: normative for the current edition of the standard, but not guaranteed to be part of the standard in future revisions.*"